# ACCESS Class not registered

Tags: ms-access, vba, office365

I've posted a question on this problem before, and since there are more and nore references to it on the web, I wanted to see if anyone in here encountered a similar problem.  I have two computers both running Windows 10 and Office 365. I get the error on the desk top when I run the following code:

```
Dim Colcon As ADODB.Connection
Set Colcon = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim ColRs As New ADODB.Recordset
ColRs.ActiveConnection = Colcon

Dim ColSQL As String
ColSQL = "SELECT ColTbl.LastDate, ColTbl.ColCode"
ColSQL = ColSQL + " FROM ColTbl"
ColRs.Open ColSQL, Colcon, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

The last line throws "Class not registered", but the same code runs perfectly on my Surface using the same environment. Have tried different solution obtained on the web, non of which work.  Just wondering if anyone else is having this problem in ACCESS. (According to the web this error can be associated with anything, when you read the posts from folks having the problem)

Thanks

Mitch' here is debug.print of Colcon.  I don't see what this has to do with the problem, but here it is. BTW I don't know what this stuff means.

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=U:\SSP Supervisor_Log\SSp_LogBook -Ver 11.accdb;
Mode=Share Deny None;Extended Properties="";
Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System1.mdw;
Jet OLEDB:Registry Path=Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\Access Connectivity Engine;
Jet OLEDB:Database Password="";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=6;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=1;
Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;
Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="";
Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;
Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;
Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False;
Jet OLEDB:Support Complex Data=True;Jet OLEDB:Bypass UserInfo Validation=False;
Jet OLEDB:Limited DB Caching=False;Jet OLEDB:Bypass ChoiceField Validation=False
```

Comment: Do you have another version or a runtime version of MS-Access installed? Are these computers both 64 bit Windows 10 systems?

Comment: Both are 64 bit running windows 10 and office 365.  FYI the same application runs on a 32 bit windows 7 system.  There is no other version of ACCESS on any of the machines.  I hope this doesn't mean a reinstall on the failing machine. Also all the drivers are up to date as well and are windows and office updates up to date.

Comment: Is your code above running in one function or in two? It seems odd that you've set the recordset connection and then open it with the "same" connection, assuming colCon variable is still valid. Can you `debug.print colCon` and copy/paste it to your question?

Comment: Mitch, I pasted Colcon into the question after the Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering about the OLEDB provider and the Access Database Engine in Office 365. Can you try a simple test of opening that same recordset using DAO? `Dim daoRS as DAO.Recordset   SET daoRS = Currentdb.OpenRecordset(ColSQL)`

Comment: Ran dao and it worked just fine.  What does that tell us about ADO problem?

Comment: I'm guessing since I rarely use ADO unless connecting to SQL Server or MySQL, but I do believe it has something to do with the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` provider and being on a 64 bit system. If you really want to persist with ADODB, you could try installing the Access 2013 Runtime Redistributable and see if the correct drivers are installed. I tend to stay away from ADO unless pushed into it.

Comment: Why do you avoid ADO, I was under the impression that it was the latest and greatest? ADO works when connecting to SQL Server, but not to a dinky ACCESS table.  Maybe we should go to chat. I'd like to learn more. But thanks for the help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121390/discussion-between-jpl458-and-dbmitch).

Comment: Sorry - won't be getting into any long winded discussions about ADO vs DAO - there's lots of information and debate out there. I've been programming in Access for 20 years and it's just a personal preference based on real life experience with both. Server based databases use very different engines than the JET DAO Engine used on Access tables. ADO was meant to work seamlessly with the SQL Server, and Oracle dbs of the world. Microsoft quit pushing (and defaulting to) ADO - and actually default to DAO in the later versions. By the way - your "dinky" Access databases can reach up to 2GB in size

Comment: and under tools->references, what reference do you have set  for ADO?

Comment: Lesson learned.  If I am accessing SQL Server use ADO.  If going after ACCESS tables use DAO.  BTW I just tried to get to a different ACCESS table with ADO and got the same error on the machine that I write the code on. ALSO I din't mean that ACCESS tables are "dinky" in general, just the one I ws trying to open.  Only one record.

Comment: And, Thanks a lot. Really learned something.  jpl458

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm if it is your install or the database by:
**Create a new database and run this in the Immediate Window:**

```
? CurrentProject.Connection
```

> If you get an error here - it rules out an issue associated
>   specifically with your database.

**If that returns an error then try a Repair of your Office365 Installation**

- Start by opening Programs and Features in the Control Panel.
  In Windows 10 you can get there by pulling up the hidden quick access menu *(To access it in Windows 10, just right-click the Start button and you’ll see a menu of a lot of the familiar built-in utilities you used in Windows 7 – including the Control Panel.*
- Select Microsoft Office 365 in the program list and then click`Change/Repair` on the command bar.
- Try the first option, `Quick Repair`, which is much faster and tries
  to fix the problem without a data connection
- If that doesn’t resolve the problem, then go back and try the `Online
  Repair` option.

Once the installation is complete, restart your computer just to be sure and launch your app and verify if the problem was resolved.

> **Reference Links**
>   [FMS Article](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/errors/class_not_registered/index.htm)
>   [Repairing Office 365](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/repair-microsoft-office-365-installation/)

Comment: It did not return an error and I have repaired Office online  several times as well as the quick repair.  From my reading I am suspecting a dll problem, but I have no clue as to what it would be or how to find it.  I just tried a couple of solutions that were on utube, but nothing works so far.

Answer (score 1):

I had this Issue with ADODB. The Class that requires registration was the data provider in the connection string. In my Case it was SQL Server Native client that needed installation. Repairing Office did absolutely nothing. But it may help for someone with a different data provider.